# Android JSON parsing, first value stored permanently

Tags: php, android, json

Am using Json parsing for my android application. There are more than 10 php files in my local host, which are given as a list view with corresponding names in my android application. When I click the first one, app will access the first php file by the name.  The JSON parsing works fine for the first php file. The description, images and videos are getting smoothly. But when I click the second ("kannur") or any other item, The second php file is executed but it still searches the first one (kasargod).

Logcat Screenshot attached at the ending.

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {


    // All static variables

    // JSON node keys
    public static int pos ;
    static final String KEY_ROOT = DistrictActivity.dist;
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_DISTRICT = "district_name"; // parent n
    static final String KEY_PLACE = "place_name";
    static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image_url";
    public static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumnail";
    public static String address="http://10.0.2.2/tour/";

    GridView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    JSONArray contacts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            final String newString = extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");


            final String URL = address+newString+".php";

            System.out.println(URL);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL



        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
             contacts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_ROOT);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                String district = c.getString(KEY_DISTRICT);
                String place = c.getString(KEY_PLACE);
                String thumnail = c.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                String image_url= c.getString(KEY_IMAGE);


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, id);
                map.put(KEY_DISTRICT, district);
                map.put(KEY_PLACE, place);
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumnail);
                map.put(KEY_IMAGE, image_url);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                placesList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

screenshot-> https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dd2l8qcj4lslsj/stack.png

ilovepjs==> KEY_ID is just consecutive digits,the newstring contains the corresponding clicks made in the list view with the values Kasargod, kannur etc, (those are the districts in kerala,India ). The php files are in the same names. And there is no error in that (I get description, images of all districts but only the first one I click returns the value, when I go back and click some other district in the list view, nothing happens!). You can understand the problem from the screenshot of Logcat attached.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is crashing here on one of these two lines

```
String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);    
String district = c.getString(KEY_DISTRICT);
```

Because it is trying to find something with a value for `kannur` i am assuming is your `KEY_ID`

Add some printlns/log messages and make sure that `KEY_ID` and `KEY_DISTRICT` contain what you want they ought to.